# What file extensions should be used on GPG generated output?

Tags: gnupg, file-extension, pgp

In Linux file name extensions are irrelevant, but on a Windows system, many GPG users use GUI applications rather than the command line. They may want to be able to double click on an encrypted file, key, or signature and open it with their GPG client.

Some extensions I have seen used a lot are `.gpg`, `.gpg-key`, `.asc`, `.sig` (plus the very verbose but self-explanatory `.gpg-revocation-certificate`), but I can't find any sort of pattern or "standard" on which extensions are recommended in which cases.

Is there a standard (or at least a common practice) for the following types of files used by GPG (or OpenPGP-based systems)?

- Exported keys
- Encrypted files
- Signatures (which includes signed files, clearsigned files, and detached signatures)
- Revocation certificates

In addition, for most of these, I would assume the file extension will differ depending on if the output is a binary or an ASCII armored file.

Comment: And if I forgot add some type of file created or used by GPG to the list, feel free to edit it in.

Comment: See my comments for this question, which seems to indicate there may be reason to care about the extensions in Linux, too: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/60213/gpg-asks-for-password-even-with-passphrase

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Normally, `.sig` is used for detached signatures using the binary OpenPGP format, and `.asc` for when the contents are ASCII-armored.

For everything else, `.gpg` is common for the binary format, `.asc` when armored.

Comment: So, you are saying that for a detached ASCII-armored signature I should probably use `.asc`?